# Terminal-like login javascript

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

I had an idea to make a terminal with CSS and Javascript. It looks like a Linux terminal and it allows user input which processes commands. I also want a way to login. Currently I have:

```
function login()
{
    var username = commandData[0];
    var password = commandData[1];

    $.post('../ajax/login.php', {username: username, password: password}, function(result) {
        if (result.error)
            writeTerminalLine(result.error);
        else
            $.post('../ajax/set-session.php', {key: 'member-id', value: result.member_id});
    });
}
```

Now, I have a feeling this isn't safe. Also, is there a way to check the result without being able to modify (like always call set-session.php). If with Javascript it isn't possible, how would I do the login in PHP with some kind of terminal?

For example, you insert `login Josh 123` in the terminal, press enter, then it processes the command header (login) and the commandData (Josh and 123).

I'm sorry if I had to post this elsewhere. I did lots of research on this but didn't really came to a 100% answer.

Oh yeah, a quick note: eventually the whole stuff will be put online and have a Cloudflare connection, so it's SSL right? So that part would be safe?

Comment: The client-side security measures IMHO should be lax. You have almost no control over clients. I suggest, though, don't set the session id by acquiring a key from the client. Create a public/private key pair and send that to the client on the handshake before even trying to log any user in. Also, try enclosing your whole JS in an anonymous function so it has its own heap and stack, and couldn't be reached from browser's console.

Comment: Didnt get it, the only thing that is maybe equal to an real terminal, is how you show/display it in the browser. The login is then done in php. like always. `feeling this isn't safe` is basiclly a different topic and has to do with protecting you server right.

Comment: @Cunning You mean some form of encryption?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions My apologize. I have a site (admin section later) which looks like a terminal. But I do an AJAX request to the login.php file, but you can easy bypass the whole stuff if you look at my code.

Comment: Simple answer is, it's secure as you make it.  Running over SSL will of course prevent sniffing.  But brute force attacks, SQL injection's etc still need to be checked for on your PHP side.  If done right, it doesn't matter if people can see your source code on the javascript end, as it's the server end were security really matters.

Comment: @Keith I know, I always check every part in PHP. But I always wonder if things like `if (result.error)` in javascript (where result is the result of the AJAX request) isn't a bad practice.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker The standard SSH requires encryption and the reason is obvious. Even if it is over an SSL, the content still can be breached on the browser-side. Using anonymous, self-invoking functions helps sealing your sensitive methods and data away from the end user. Also look into HTML5's `keygen` tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_keygen.asp .

Comment: @Cunning Oh well I don't have much experience with SSL and encryption (I only read something basically about RSA and AES encryption but not much). Also, that example on w3schools uses a form, but in my case it's different as I use only Javascript. And how can I do it without an user having to click a button? (I might use it later for something different which all users can access).

Comment: @Cunning looks like keygen tag is being deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen

Comment: @cronfy It doesn't help much anyways.